# What solutions exsist to fill in the gap between the bottom of garage door and cement?

Tags: garage-door

What are some good options or approaches to fill in a large gap under garage door after having the driveway redone. It's a decent size gap.

I've tried resetting the garage door opener but it is at the lowest point it can go.

Do they make weather strips and such that will fill this gap correctly, or do I need to fill the gap with something else?

Added a photo, I'll have to get some measurements.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you actually measure the gap. 'Decent size' isn't going to help people make suggestions.

Comment: Not sure what reset the garage door opener means. With some openers you can disengage the door from the openers track then set the door down to the slab and reengage the drive mechanism and the door will be positioned properly. More information about the gap and about the garage door opener is needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How thickly can I install self levelling concrete to fix a tilted garage floor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/204310/how-thickly-can-i-install-self-levelling-concrete-to-fix-a-tilted-garage-floor)

Comment: @SolarMike  I'm not sure that your duplicate is actually a duplicate.  Similar problem, but it's asking about different solutions.

Answer (score 3):

One option based on the information given is to install a heavy duty rubber stripping on the bottom of the door similar to the item shown below.
[image]

This particular photo is from Amazon but search "garage door bottom seal" and all sorts will pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the one photo it appears the gap is relatively even across the full width -- there's no high or low spot preventing closure. Make sure you have some kind of seal installed on the bottom edge of the door. A bulb style like the one in JACK's answer is great.

It sounds as if you've already tried to adjust the door operator's range of travel but it is already at its limit. Inspect the door, the jamb, the rollers, the arm that attaches the door to the operator trolley, and the trolley position. Figure out what's preventing the door from closing further. Is a roller or roller bracket running into something? Is the operator trolley hitting a stop at the end of its rail?

If the trolley position is the limiting factor you could try disconnecting the door arm from the trolley. If the door can close fully when disconnected from the operator then adjust that linkage/arm so it's a little longer. The travel limits of the operator will have to be adjusted again after this is done.